# Google Ads removed by uninstalling com.google.android.gms

Tags: google-play-store, adb, ads

Recently, I'm testing with my Android 6.0 phone and ADB tools. I list all applications with `pm list packages`. After installing and uninstalling (i.e. trial and error) some of the applications, I find that if I uninstall these two applications, other applications does not shows any type of advertises. Then I copy those APK files in SD card and execute these two commands with `adb.exe shell` to uninstall those two application.

```
pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.vending.apk
pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.gms.apk
```

[image: com.google.android.gms]

Though I'm pleased with removing all advertises, I saw that Google Play Store and Google Account vanished from Home Screen. But I reinstall them from the APK files and it works properly.

**Question:** Is Google Play application responsible for all those advertises in other apps? Can I remove those Ads providing links between apps and Play Store?

N.B: I'm new to this site. This question may be duplicate. I didn't find appreciable answer in other questions.

Comment: For ads in apps - developers are responsible for them. Deleting Google services won't remove any ads, it may only prevent showing targeted ads, but maybe not even that. P.s. if you delete Google services you won't be able to access play store and a lot of apps won't work even if you install it via .apk

Comment: It's generally speaking a very bad idea to remove these, unless you know what you're doing...which you probably don't since you're asking here. I had a bad experience with unmatched versions after a careless update. This resulted in [all google-based in-app maps broken](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/185992/how-to-fix-in-app-google-maps-after-google-play-services-update-broke-map-func). As mentioned below, use a non-root adblocker or VPN based firewall. (I.e *AdGuard* or [NetGuard](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/releases).

Comment: @not2qubit I only do an experiment as I thought before that all apps separately connected to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, ads come from two sources -apps and targeted ads by Google

For the latter removing [GMS Services](https://www.android.com/gms/) doesn't help, rather creates problems as you discovered , since GMS

> Google Mobile Services (GMS) is a collection of Google applications and APIs that help support functionality across devices. These apps work together seamlessly to ensure your device provides a great user experience right out of the box

Better ways to get rid of apps :

- Follow steps mentioned in [Google support](https://support.google.com/ads/answer/2662850?hl=en) - not very effective
- Sign out of ads when you set up your Google account
- Use an ad-blocker app which takes care of ads from both sources. [Adguard](https://adguard.com/en/welcome.html)
  is one good app if your device is not rooted. If it's rooted, your choice widens and is more effective

PS : I am not associated with Adguard but properly configured , it's great a way to get rid of apps and also have firewall

Also see this for more information [Where is data of Google Play Services located in device? Can I safely delete it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/117582/131553)